# Xamarin iOS: Dynamic update for UICollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, mvvmcross

In my xamarin ios project, I am populating the images in UICollectionView cells.It has the ability to delete or rotate the image.I was wondering is there any way I could update the cells as soon as the source changes ?

Cell :

```
public class MyCellCollectionViewSource: MvxCollectionViewSource 
{
    public ObservableCollection < Animal > animals;
    ViewModel1 vm;
    public MyCellCollectionViewSource(ViewModel1 vm, int noOfImages) : base(collectionView) 
    {
        this.vm = vm;
        animals = new ObservableCollection < Animal > ();
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfImages; i++) {
            //animals.Add(i);
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                animals.Add(new Animal() {
                    indexCell = 1,
                    image = vm.Photo1
                });
                break;
            case 1:
                animals.Add(new Animal() {
                    indexCell = 2,
                    image = vm.Photo2
                });
                break;
            case 2:
                animals.Add(new Animal() {
                    indexCell = 3,
                    image = vm.Photo3
                });
                break;
            case 3:
                animals.Add(new Animal() {
                    indexCell = 4,
                    image = vm.Photo4
                });
                break;
            case 4:
                animals.Add(new Animal() {
                    indexCell = 5,
                    image = vm.Photo5
                });
                break;
            case 5:
                animals.Add(new Animal() {
                    indexCell = 1,
                    image = newPostDetailViewModel.Photo1
                });
                break;
            }

        }
        public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath) 
        {
            var cell = (MyCell) collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(animalCellId, indexPath);
            Cell.PopulateCell(indexPath.Row);
            cell.Closebtn.TouchUpInside += delegate {
                MyCellCollectionViewSource source = collectionView.DataSource as MyCellCollectionViewSource;
                vm.DeleteCommand.Execute(indexPath.Row);
                ReloadData();
            };

            cell.UserPostbtn.TouchUpInside += delegate {
                MyCellCollectionViewSource source = collectioview.DataSource as MyCellCollectionViewSource;
                newPostDetailViewModel.EditPhotoCommand.Execute(indexPath.Row);
                ReloadData();
            };
        }

    }
```

The cell has CloseBtn and UserPostBtn.

When I hit CloseBtn, I can see in my observableCollection 'animals' that the cell is deleted. But I cannot see them reflected on my collectionview, If i go back and reload the complete page again, then I can see my changes.

Same way, If I click on UserPostBtn, it would rotate the image but those are changes are not reflected dynamically, I would have to go back and reload the reload the whole page to update the cells.

Comment: Does Animal Implement INotifyPropertyChanged? Are you making sure that changes to your ObservableCollection occur on UI thread?

Comment: Animal does implement INotifyPrepertyChange. How can I make sure its occurring in UIThread ?